# Do you think the question "Advanced MCMC samplers in R for calibration of a computer model" belong on SO, CV or nowhere on SE?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, r, software

I try to never ask R-related questions on Cross Validated. However, I asked the question [Advanced MCMC samplers in R for calibration of a computer model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42022917/advanced-mcmc-samplers-in-r-for-calibration-of-a-computer-model) on SO and apparently it wasn't well-received (it's true that little time has passed, though). Do you think it would be better suited to CV?

Comment: It's a little early to be sure about the SO reception (2 hours since your posting on SO as I write). I am not an R user and I wouldn't vote on a question like that, but broad, discursive questions rarely succeed on SO in my experience. Conversely, the R focus of that question would make that problematic for CV. Although people are often surprised or annoyed to hear it, there can be questions that fall in a great gap between the forums. They don't share a continuous land border.

Comment: @NickCox, yes, it was a bit early but my (admittedly limited) experience with SO is that a question who gets downvoted so quickly remains unanswered, and while the question has been upvoted afterwards, it looks like I was right. Back to your point, you believe the question is out of place on CV. I'm not so sure now (see [Scortchi's comment to my other question](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4586/where-to-learn-about-r-packages)). Let's see if someone else chimes in here. I agree, though, that there can be questions which are just out of place on Stack Exchange.

Comment: IMO, a question just asking for a package is off topic here. If you want to ask about different MCMC sampling algorithms & which is best for your situation, that seems potentially on topic to me--it's software-neutral eg.

Comment: @gung ok, I'll try asking such a question. Let's see what happens.

Comment: @amoeba I agree this is a duplicate, and my answer there addresses this question.

Comment: @amoeba Ok, do I delete it or are you guys going to close it?